# JavaScript event handler isn't called on appended button

Tags: javascript

I have form where I can add options and add new fields of options. I am using JQuery for this. The problem is that the remove button of added fields doesn't work.

Here's my form:

[image: one]

## Logic

1. I click `Add New` button and new row will add **Working**
2. I click `Remove` it has to remove that row **Not Working**

```js
$(function() {

  //add row for options
  $("#addnewoptinrow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.newrow').append('<div class="row mt-3 newrowadded"><div class="col-md-8"><input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-danger" id="removerow">Remove</button></div></div>');
  });

  //Remove the row
  $('.removerow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.newrowadded').closest("div.row").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="addnewqtydiscmsgsave btn btn-primary" id="addnewoptinrow">Add New</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newrow"></div>
```

**Any idea how to fix that remove action?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @Aydin4ik thanks but no those solutions are not my answers regarding that my code is similar to accepted answer in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- the call to `on()` is [missing the "selector" argument](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data), which means that no elements dynamically added in future will have the click event boundy
- your remove logic needs to be executed relative to the button being clicked

Try the following changes in your `.removerow` click handler:

```
/* 
Bind the click handler to all elements dynamically added that match the
.removerow selector 
*/
$('body').on('click','.removerow', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    /* 
    Explaination:
    1. from "this" remove button being clicked, 
    2. select the closest ".newrowadded" and, 
    3. remove it 
    */
    $(this).closest(".newrowadded").remove();
});
```

See the snippet below for your a working example based off of your code:

```js
$(function() {

  //add row for options
  $("#addnewoptinrow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.newrow').append('<div class="row mt-3 newrowadded"><div class="col-md-8"><input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-danger">Remove</button></div></div>');
  });

  //Remove the row
  $('body').on('click', '.removerow', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".newrowadded").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="addnewqtydiscmsgsave btn btn-primary" id="addnewoptinrow">Add New</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newrow"></div>
```

Comment: still not removing the row

Comment: `"jquery": "^3.2",`

Comment: could be because my code is in bootstrap modal? however my add button is in modal as well but working :)

Comment: sorry my error, I forgot an argument on the `on()` method - does the updated answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is only being executed on page load and at this time, your remove button is not yet created. You need to add an event listener to the remove button **after** your remove button has been created.

Comment: I thought `.on` did that?

Comment: If they're using jQuery 1.7 or above then this happens automatically

Comment: i am using `"jquery": "^3.2",`

Answer (score 0):

In oder to match your event listener to later created elements, you need to delegate it. In older JQuery versions it was done by the `.delegate` method, however, in recent versions this method is deprecated. Now you can delegate by `ancestorCollection.on('query-selector', 'event', listener)`.

In your example something like

```
$('.newrow').on('.removerow', 'click', function(e){ /*...*/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to bind actions on elements that are not yet created - you should use a more general binding as below:

```js
$(function(){

    //add row for options
    $("#addnewoptinrow").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.newrow').append('<div class="row mt-3 newrowadded"><div class="col-md-8"><input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-danger" class="removerow">Remove</button></div></div>');
    });

    //Remove the row
    $(document).on('click','.removerow', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input name="optionsprices[]"  type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="addnewqtydiscmsgsave btn btn-primary" id="addnewoptinrow">Add New</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="newrow"></div>
```

Pay attention to the

```
$(document).on('click','.removerow', function(e){
```

line of code. This line appends the action to all of the '.removerow' elements, present and future. So when new elements are added with this class, they are automatically assigned this action (BTW, had to change your HTML from `id="removerow"` to `class="removerow"`, to avoid duplicate ID's).

And please read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements), it goes into more details of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Button.removerow` was added later. you can try this:

```
  //add row for options
  $("#addnewoptinrow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.newrow').append('<div class="row mt-3 newrowadded"><div class="col-md-8"><input name="options[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Name"></div><div class="col-md-2"><input name="optionsprices[]" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-danger" id="removerow">Remove</button></div></div>');


    //Remove the row
    $('.removerow').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.newrowadded').closest("div.row").remove();
    });
  });
```